# Query runs very slow with big tables

Tags: sql, optimization, sql-server-2016

Having the following 2 tables:

Table **MainProcessed**:

```
Id  Value
---------
1   123
2   234
3   112
```

Table **MainAdditionalInfo**:

```
Id  MainProcessedId Name    Value
--------------------------------------
1   1               'PX'    'px_value'
2   1               'PY'    'py_value'
```

I need to select all the data from the table `MainProcessedId` that has some additional info in the table `MainAdditionalInfo` (at least one record) and it doesn't have a record with the name PX or if it has, this value should be null or empty.

This is what I've tried, but since these tables have a lot of data (more that 100 millions of records, the query is running for a lot of time):

```
select mp.*
from MainProcessed mp (nolock)
left join MainAdditionalInfo mai1 (nolock) on mp.Id = mai1.MainProcessedId
left join MainAdditionalInfo mai2 (nolock) on mp.Id = mai2.MainProcessedId
where
    (mai1.Value is null or mai1.Value = '')
    and (mai1.Name = 'PX' or mai1.Name = null)
    and mai2.name = 'PY'
```

Note that the value with the name PX might not be present or can be present with a null or empty value, but the value with the name PY it's always present. Can you suggest me an improving?

Also, I don't have the rights to see the execution plans or to create new objects (indexes).

Comment: What indexes do you have on your tables? (include the DDL for the tables and all the indexes) Do you really need all the columns from the table `MainProcessed`? Why are you (very likely) misusing the `NOLOCK` hint, or do you understand the (huge) implications is has on your data? You also need to include your queries plans. We can't help you unless you give us all the information about your query, and tables.

Comment: Also, why handle `NULL` in the `WHERE` and not just include the clause without the `NULL` in the `ON`? Why a second `LEFT JOIN` to `MainAdditionalInfo` when the value of `name` **must** be `'PY'`? Should it actually be an `INNER JOIN` (as it is at the moment)? Seems like everything in your `WHERE` should be in your `ON`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try and phrase your query with `exists` and `not exists`:

```
select p.*
from MainProcessed p
where 
    exists (
        select 1 
        from MainAdditionalInfo a 
        where a.MainProcessedId = p.id)
    and not exists (
        select 1 
        from MainAdditionalInfo a 
        where 
            a.MainProcessedId = p.id 
            and a.Name = 'PX' 
            and a.Value <> ''    -- null values won't pass that test
    )
```

For performance with this query, you want an index on `MainAdditionalInfo(MainProcessedId , Name, Value)`.

Comment: you don't have a condition to include only records where exists MainAdditionalInfo with neme PY

Comment: @AdamSilenko . . . Presumably, that is because the question is not clear that that is necessary.

Comment: _Note that the value with the name PX might not be present or can be present with a null or empty value, but the value with the name PY it's always present._

Answer (score 0):

```
select mp.*
from MainProcessed mp
left join MainAdditionalInfo mai1 on mp.Id = mai1.MainProcessedId and mai2.name ='PX'
where Id in(
    select distinct MainProcessedId
    from MainAdditionalInfo mai2
        inner join MainProcessed on Id = mai2.MainProcessedId and mai2.name ='PY'
    )
    and (mai1.Value is null or mai1.Value = '')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment, but I'm expanding on my second one. This doesn't, also, answer the question (there's not enough detail in the question to answer it), but it might help the query planner anyway.

Firstly, you have 2 clauses in you `WHERE`, like `(mai1.Value is null or mai1.Value = '')` I *assume* this is because `Value` might be `NULL` if the `JOIN` fails. If so, don't handle it in your `WHERE`, put it in the `ON`.

You also have `and mai2.name = 'PY'`, however, you perform a `LEFT JOIN` to`MainAdditionalInfo mai2`. This means the `JOIN` is now an implicit `INNER JOIN`. I would, therefore, personally write your query as:

```
SELECT {List columns, do not use *}
FROM MainProcessed mp
     JOIN MainAdditionalInfo mai2 ON mp.Id = mai2.MainProcessedId
     LEFT JOIN MainAdditionalInfo mai1 ON mp.Id = mai1.MainProcessedId
                                      AND mai1.Value = ''
                                      AND mai1.Name = 'PX'
WHERE mai2.[name] = 'PY';
```

I've also removed the `NOLOCK` hints, as I suspect they do far more harm than good. [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: it will return MainProcessedId that have a record with the name PX... you don't have exclude a condition

Comment: I don'; follow, @AdamSilenko . The OP's query has no "exclude" condition. I've literally taken their existing query and rewritten it with more logical syntax.

Comment: it has, because this conditions `(mai1.Value is null or mai1.Value = '') and (mai1.Name = 'PX' or mai1.Name = null)` are in where clausule....

Comment: @AdamSilenko , Those state the value must be "this" or "that". And I have moved those clauses to the `ON`, and assumed `Value` and `Name` would only have the value `NULL` when the `JOIN` fails; meaning that there's no need to check in the `ON`. The OP, however, in *their* query *has* not `<>`/`!=` or `NOT` expressions.

Comment: if you have left join and condition that you expect null data or only something specific, then it is some exclusions, but maybe I know nothing about that...

Comment: No, @AdamSilenko that isn't right. If you have the query `SELECT * FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID WHERE T2.Col1 = 'abc' OR T2.Col1 IS NULL;`  you would be far better off moving the `T2.Col1 = 'abc'` clause to the `ON` for the **same** behaviour: `SELECT * FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID AND T2.Col1 = 'abc;'`

Comment: [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3aa9c2df6f39392d422d551dc8b1b9a8)

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c9a2e92142d7caa9dc6394318d8064af

Answer (score 0):

At first, you should ensure that you have FK on `MainAdditionalInfo` to `MainProcessed.ID` with index on `MainAdditionalInfo.MainProcessedId`. Also, you should have an index on `MainAdditionalInfo` at columns `name` and `value`.
Don't use `join` if you don't need data from `MainAdditionalInfo`, use `exists`, for example:

```
SELECT mp.*
FROM MainProcessed mp (nolock)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MainAdditionalInfo mai1
  WHERE mai1.Value > '' 
  AND mai1.Name = 'PX' 
  AND mp.Id = mai1.MainProcessedId)
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MainAdditionalInfo mai2 
  WHERE mai2.name = 'PY' 
  AND mp.Id = mai2.MainProcessedId)
```